# Read a PDF file with multiple text box Like in patent files in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I use R to analyze PDF documents. I face a problem when I try to read a PDF document with several columns. The document is read line by line and that make a mixture of the text. I would like to be able to read column after column can anyone help me please?

This is how I'm reading a document

```
library(tm)
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
Rpdf <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))(elem = list(uri = files), language="en", id="id1")
```

[image: example of document]